# Flutter: CustomPainter Destination image not dropping on BlendMode.src

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to learn `CustomPainter`. I have created two rectangles successfully and trying to understand `BlendMode`.

As the document says when setting `paintObj.blendMode = BlendMode.src`, it should

> Drop the destination image, only paint the source image.`

But here both destination and source painted on top of each other and not clearing destination.

This is full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paintObj = Paint();

    paintObj.color = Colors.red;
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero),
        radius: 40.0,
      ),
      paintObj,
    );

    paintObj.blendMode = BlendMode.src;

    paintObj.color = Colors.green;
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero),
        height: 160,
        width: 40,
      ),
      paintObj,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Result:**
I don't know why the red rectangle(destination) is still drawn

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to behave as expected.

Documentation of `Paint`'s `blendMode`:

```
/// A blend mode to apply when a shape is drawn or a layer is composited.
///
/// The source colors are from the shape being drawn (e.g. from
/// [Canvas.drawPath]) or layer being composited (the graphics that were drawn
/// between the [Canvas.saveLayer] and [Canvas.restore] calls), after applying
/// the [colorFilter], if any.
///
/// The destination colors are from the background onto which the shape or
/// layer is being composited.
///
/// Defaults to [BlendMode.srcOver].
```

Documentation of `BlendMode.src`:

```
/// Drop the destination image, only paint the source image.
///
/// Conceptually, the destination is first cleared, then the source image is
/// painted.
```

I believe the destination is considered to be the rectangle below the green rectangle (of the exact same size), not the entire canvas. This would make sense as it would give `CustomPainer` a lot more flexibility compared to clearing the entire canvas. You should be able to test this by using semi-transparent colors. If my assumption is correct, the semi-transparent green rectangle should have uniform color because the red rectangle would be cleared from underneath it first.

Comment: Thank you now I can understand what is going on. But when I set `Colors.green.withOpacity(0.0)` then i am getting black color instead of white(`Scaffold`'s background). I assume its because removes all painting from the default layer?

Comment: I solved this by adding `canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint())` at start and adding `canvas.restore()` at end. Is it good to do that or any better way to avoid that black (or empty) space?.

Comment: I don't have much experience with it so I don't know, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. I just want to understand `BlendMode.src` and other `BlendMode` values. Your answer helped lot to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paintObj = Paint();

    canvas.saveLayer(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width, size.height), radius: 100),
        paintObj);

    paintObj.color = Colors.red;

    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero),
        radius: 40.0,
      ),
      paintObj,
    );

    paintObj.blendMode = BlendMode.src;

    paintObj.color = Colors.green;
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero),
        height: 160,
        width: 40,
      ),
      paintObj,
    );

    canvas.restore();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But its weird. Your solution works on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). But not working on the android emulator. It just displays the white color (`Scaffold`'s background)